# SM8 package orientation

Tags: packages

I've received chips PCA9306DCTR (from Texas Instruments) but they don't have any dot or notch to define it's orientation (i.e. where is the pin 1).

In the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9306.pdf) there is a picture of this chip (in SM8 package) and it has a notch. However chips I've received has only strip of different color (please see the [picture](http://postimg.org/image/9odq0rqct/)) and I've not found any information about it's meaning.

[image]

So, is this strip mark pins GND and EN (i.e. the same as dot or notch) or it marks SDA1 and SDA2?

Comment: I would bet it mark GND-EN, but, yes it's just a bet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stripe marks the Pin 1 end. With Pin 1 to the left, the rest of the text is right way up, as further confirmation - as has been the convention on all DIP ICs (and SOIC) I have ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the prints on it are the key: for read the code "7bd 23y" you have to put it over your table in a certain way. And then the pin 1 will be the lower left one.

Answer (score 1):

So just what is the inked square on the corner. Looks like a pin one marker to me.

[image]

Comment: It's just a reflection of light (chip is very small, so I zoomed image a lot). But anyway thanks for you reply!